# retrieve data from array in Angularjs and pass it to id

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the view passing values to the controller and I take this and store it into array. But afterwards I am willing to grab the value in the array and pass it into the value of id in update method.

Here is what I have

**HTML**

```
 <label class="control-label col-xs-8 col-sm-3 no-padding-right" >Choose a Plate</label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">

                <select id="plateId" ng-model="selectedPlate" ng-options="plate as (plate.wafer_id + ' - ' + plate.serial_number) for plate in plates" ng-change="getSelectedPlateID(selectedPlate)"/>
                    <option value="">Select</option>



                </select>
```

And here is **my controller**

```
 $scope.plateid = [];


            $scope.inspectionData = {

                equipment_status_codes_id: 1,
                plate_container_id: 1,
                plate_container_slot: 21,
                plate_quality_id: 1

            }

        PlatesFactory.query(function(plates)
        {
            $scope.plates = plates;

        });

        $scope.getSelectedPlateID = function(item)
        {
          $scope.plateid.push({
              plate_id : item.id
         });

          console.log($scope.plateid[0]);
         //alert(item.wafer_id)

        }
            // I have no clue what I am doing wrong here, but it just not working. I can't seem to update the object on the database  

        PlatesInspectionFactory.update( {id : $scope.plateid[0]}, $scope.inspectionData)
```

someone here suggested using

```
{id : $scope.plateid[0].plate_id,
```

but this wont work.

I am stuck with this like for a day or two. Somemone help please.

Comment: It seems that information you provided is not enough to help you. Here i made fiddle emulating your case: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18691/. Can you update it to make your point more clear.

Comment: @Dfr Thanks for making a live demo. I have updated with a function called `storePlatesInspection` But it's not working. Could you take a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing values to object and trying to access it in wrong way. I have created a fiddle which will explain it http://jsfiddle.net/az40Lxw8/2/

Try below

```
 $scope.plateid = [];


        $scope.inspectionData = {

            equipment_status_codes_id: 1,
            plate_container_id: 1,
            plate_container_slot: 21,
            plate_quality_id: 1

        }

    PlatesFactory.query(function(plates)
    {
        $scope.plates = plates;

    });

    $scope.getSelectedPlateID = function(item)
    {
      $scope.plateid.push({
          plate_id : item.id
     });

      console.log($scope.plateid[0]);
     //alert(item.wafer_id)

    }
        // I have no clue what I am doing wrong here, but it just not working. I can't seem to update the object on the database  

    PlatesInspectionFactory.update( {id : $scope.plateid[0].plate_id}, $scope.inspectionData)
```

Comment: This is not the problem, sir. I am having problem with PlatesInspectionFactory.update id which is not receiving the id from plateid array.  Thanks for suggestion

Comment: What you get when you do console log on $scope.plateid[0]

Comment: I guess the issue is same like I mentioned above.  I have edited my answer, chek it once

Comment: I have places `PlatesInspectionFactory.update( {id : $scope.plateid[0].plate_id}, $scope.inspectionData)` in function `getSelectedPlateID` and it worked. But now I have put it into a function `
       ` $scope.storePlatesInspection = function()
        {

             PlatesInspectionFactory.update( {id : $scope.plateid[0]}, $scope.inspectionData, function()
    {
     // to something
    })`

        and it's not working. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/az40Lxw8/3/ with a function. I have solved the first part. But now with a function it won't work. Thanks a lot

Comment: If my answer could have solved your purpose which you mentioned at first in question then, be kind to accept the answer. I would suggest to create new Question have your other query with updated code